# Windows 10 - Location of docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am using Windows 10. I installed docker and pulled an image following this github
https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker

```
docker pull floydhub/dl-docker:cpu
```

Now I can't seem to find where this image is located if I want to delete it and download another copy. When I used a the VMware virtual machine there would be a specific folder with the name designated by me. So how do I look for the folder containing this docker image ?

Comment: I found this useful [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250222/what-is-docker-image-location-on-windows-10#_=_)

Answer (score 12):

`windows systray -> docker for windows -> docker settings -> advanced ->  disk image location`

result, something like

`C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data\DockerDesktop.vhdx`
[image]

Comment: Settings look different for me: on the left there is just *General*, *Resources*, *Docker Engine*, *Experimental Features* and *Kubernetes* -

Comment: Of course, the setting might differ for the particular configuration plus evolve with years, and the questions might need to be updated.

Answer (score 11):

[This thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/where-are-images-stored/9794/8) might help.  Essentially, according to Michael Friis,  docker images are stored in the Hyper-VM and the Hyper-V VM harddrive itself is usually in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User - we expect answers to be self contained, especially with something factual like this. Links can go stale, rendering your answer completely useless. You might want to distil the useful parts of that thread *into* your answer, referring back where appropriate, then flag to reopen.